# wpf binding max width proportional to other element's width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following ItemTemplate:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                           
        <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="{Binding SenderId, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"
                MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SideBar}"
                HorizontalAlignment="{Binding SenderId, Converter={StaticResource AlignmentConverter}}">

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

What I would like to do is to bind the Border elements MaxWidth property to 70% of the SideBar's Width but I can't seem to find a way to do this in xaml.
Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: You have to use `IValueConverter` to do the calculation. XAML only solution is not feasible in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Rohit Vats comment:

Add this class to your solution:

```
public class ElementSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double percentage = double.Parse(parameter.ToString());

        return double.Parse(value.ToString()) * percentage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, in your XAML, declare the namespace of where this class is in the document header:

```
xmlns:ConverterNamespace="clr-namespace:ConverterNamespace"
```

Instantiate the converter in the resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ConverterNamespace:ElementSizeConverter x:Key="ElementSizeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then you can use the following binding:

```
Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=elementName, Converter={StaticResource ElementSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.7}"
```

*Note: I couldn't get ActualWidth to work, but play around with this and see if this works for you.*

Answer (score 1):

By nesting in a grid you could also get the percentages:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />                            
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>           
            <Border Grid.Column="1"
                    CornerRadius="5" 
                    Background="{Binding SenderId, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{Binding SenderId, Converter={StaticResource AlignmentConverter}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Border>
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```